# How to show the a sequence converges to 0 almost surely

Tags: stochastic-processes, convergence

There are two nonnegative sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$. We know that

$a_nb_n$ is summable a.s., i.e., $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n < +\infty$ a.s..
$a_n$ is not summable a.s., i.e., $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=+\infty$ a.s..

Can we say that $b_n$ converges to 0 a.s.? 
I am new to this topic, and this question is too simple. If it is, is there any reference for it?

Comment: The reference is the homework solutions which will be distributed when your graded homework is returned.  My apologies in advance if this is for a take home exam rather than a homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequences $a_n = 0$ when $n$ is even, $a_n = 1$ when $n$ is odd, and $b_n = 1 - a_n$.  I think you can take it from here.

Comment: what if $a_n>0$ for all $n$?

Comment: It still isn't true. Take $a_n = 1/n$ and $b_n = 1$ if $n$ is a perfect square otherwise $b_n = 0$. Where does this problem come up?